# strange output while printing float as integer and integer as float in C

Tags: c, output

the following code is not showing the expected output which is garbage value ( strangely the values are swapped )

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float f = 4.6;
    int d = 7;
    printf("%d %f\n",f,d);
    return 0;
}
```

output:
7 4.600000

Comment: Why not really make a mess: `printf("%d %f\n",(int)f,(float)d);`

Comment: Standard says: C11 7.21.6.1: "*If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*"

Comment: So don't do that. Some compilers (gcc in particular) can warn about mismatched arguments to `printf` when the format string is a literal, but in general it's entirely up to you to call `printf` correctly.

Comment: Which ABI is that (processor, compiler, ...)?  I guess integers and floating point values are passed in different registers.

Comment: If you compile with `gcc -Wall -g` you'll get a warning message, and you'll then improve your faulty source code in seconds.

Comment: Either enable your all compiler warnings (it should catch this) or get a new compiler.

Comment: @starblue: Usually the compiler vendor complies with the OS vendor's ABI which is influenced by the whims of a particular processor design. I believe that Sun SPARC at some point passed the first `n` _simple_ arguments in processor registers, and the rest on some sort of stack. (For some value of `n` and some definition of _simple_.)

Answer (score 2):

Let's reduce this a bit:

```
float f = 4.6;
printf("%d\n", f);
```

That's **undefined behavior**. The correct format specifier must be given an argument of the correct type.

Undefined behavior can cause any outcome, including this odd outcome that you are seeing.

### Further thoughts:

Now, you might be asking why a compiler would even produce this code. So let's look at the x86-64 assembly for 2 codes:

```
int main() {
    float f = 4.6;
    int d = 7;
    printf("%d %f\n", d, f);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    float f = 4.6;
    int d = 7;
    printf("%f %d\n", f, d);
    return 0;
}
```

Other than the format string, these two codes produce identical assembly. This is likely because the calling convention requires floats to be placed in different registers than integers, or that floats should be passed on the stack (or any number of other rules that handle floats and integers differently).

This should make it clearer why the code you posted is still producing something useful, even though the code is just broken.

Answer (score 1):

The argument corresponding to `%d` must be an `int`, and the argument corresponding to `%f` must be a double. Arguments to variadic functions undergo some standard conversions (so `float` will be converted to `double` automatically), but they're not automatically converted to the appropriate types for their corresponding `printf` format specifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Not really hard to understand.  The float value is passed in float registers, while the int value is passed in the conventional parameter stack.  So when the values are referenced, they are fetched from different areas and it magically works, even though is shouldn't (and won't, on a different box).

Answer (score 0):

For example, gcc 4.7.2 for amd64 does this, because integer and floating-point arguments are passed in different registers.  This effectively reorders the arguments.

From "System V Application Binary Interface. AMD64 Architecture Processor Supplement. Draft Version 0.99.6" (floating-point numbers have class SSE):

1. If the class is INTEGER, the next available register of the sequence %rdi,%rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used.
2. If the class is SSE, the next available vector register is used, the registers
   are taken in the order from %xmm0 to %xmm7.

Of course you should not do this and enable warnings to catch it during compilation.